# Change where git see's .ssh public key

Tags: git

Setting up git on a new corporate laptop.  It seems my corporation auto maps the %home% directory from AD.  I was able to change the local settings for the git home settings using VIM.  That allowed me to set up the ssh to my user drive locally, BUT when I try to test the connection using" ssh –T git@github.com." it always points back to the Y: Drive which is my home network location. and it fails the test.  Testing git with elevated privileges works, I still won't be able to use it in vscode.

Can I change where git looks for the ssh key?  Currently looking towards a network location, even though I was able to install it to my c:/users/username

At first, i noticed that git in its entirety was pointing to my Y drive. But using VIM I changed the directory to the c:/users/username.  This allowed me to create a new ssh key and place it locally.

I also used the c\users\ in the ssh-keygen –t rsa –b 4096 –C "YOURGITHUBEMAIL@PLACEHOLDER.NET" part which helped set it.

Comment: Is this a git problem? Or is this an ssh problem? I suspect it's the latter. Are you able to ssh to any other hosts on the corporate network which require an ssh key for authentication? Try `ssh -v <some.company.hostname> 'hostname'` and see if ssh is fetching your key from the expected location. Consider adding the output of this command to your post (but leave out any secure or confidential info, of course).

Comment: I'm only connecting the laptop to github.  Whenever i connect to my companies network github changes the home directory to the network drive directory (if im off the network it defaults back to local).  I've changed the directory using VIM to the local user directory, but git will still try to go to the network location y/~.ssh to get the ssh keys.  I'm looking for a way to force git to always check the local user drive for ssh, regardless of if the userdrive is connected.

Comment: I maintain the belief that this is an ssh issue. Unless you are dealing with a pre-existing repository - which you've already ruled out by trying `ssh -T git@github.com` - git doesn't know or care where your ssh keys live. What happens when you try `ssh -T -i /path/to/your/private_key git@github.com`? Does your `~/.ssh/config` file have any `IdentityFile` entries?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, AD group policy was changing the homedrive which in git, no matter where you map it locally, it still looks to your %HOMEDRIVE%  for the location of your SSH files.

This was fixed creating a cmd script as such:

C:\Windows\System32\userinit.cmd containing

@ECHO OFF SET HOMEDRIVE=C: SET HOMEPATH=\Users\%USERNAME% SET HOMESHARE=\localhost\C$\Users\%USERNAME% @START C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

And placing it in the system32 folder then changing the registry entry below:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
 to 
C:\Windows\System32\userinit.cmd

This forces the homedrive to the local location before the userinit file is run.

So no it wasn't a SSH issue.